# Making cells bold in a table using python-docx

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

The code snippet below basically creates a table with the required number of rows and columns in a new word document i.e 2 columns and 14 rows. It then adds the content to the rows and columns accordingly.

```
from docx import Document
newDoc=Document()
newDoc.add_heading ('GIS Request Form')
newDoc.add_paragraph()

#inserting a table and the header and value objects to the table
 table=newDoc.add_table(rows=14,cols=2)
 table.style='Table Grid'
 table.autofit=False
 table.columns[0].width=2500000
 table.columns[1].width=3500000

 #inserting contents into table cells
 for i in range(0,14):
   row=table.rows[i]
   row.cells[0].text=reqdheaderList[i]
   row.cells[1].text=reqdvalueList[i]
```

I have been trying to make the contents of everything in column 1 bold, but it is not working.

```
  #inserting contents into table cells
   for i in range(0,14):
     row=table.rows[i]
     row.cells[0].text=reqdheaderList[i]
     row.cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run(line[0]).bold=True
     row.cells[1].text=reqdvalueList[i]
```

Help?

Answer (score 11):

Expanding @Nikos Tavoularis answer; you can also add a helper function. E.g.:

```py
from docx import Document

def make_rows_bold(*rows):
    for row in rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                for run in paragraph.runs:
                    run.font.bold = True

doc = Document()

table = doc.add_table(rows=4, cols=2)
table.cell(0, 0).text = "Some text"
table.cell(1, 0).text = "Some bold text"
table.cell(1, 1).text = "Some more bold text"
table.cell(2, 0).text = "Some text"
table.cell(3, 1).text = "And more bold text"

make_rows_bold(table.rows[1], table.rows[3])

doc.save('test.docx')
```

Writing more functions like `make_rows_bold` can make working with `docx` way more pleasant.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve that using the following loop:

```py
bolding_columns = [0]
for row in list(range(14)):
    for column in bolding_columns:
        table.rows[row].cells[column].paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.bold = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You may re-write these two lines

```py
     row.cells[0].text=reqdheaderList[i]
     row.cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run(line[0]).bold=True
```

to

```py
     row.cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run(reqdheaderList[i]).bold=True
```

Comment: Can we also add a hyperlink to the text which is bold? The hyperlink should reference to a paragraph within the document.